# Mac OS X list of bundles in system by id

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Could you propose solution for search all bundles of application in system by id synchronously?

For example you can have application with version 10.4 and 10.5, but it have same bundle id.

Answer (score 1):

You can grab a NSFileManager instance and recursively go through either /Applications (if your interested in only this location), or / if you want to search the whole file system. And for each folder you can use the isFilePackageAtPath: of NSWorkspace to find out if that folder is a bundle. From here you can use +[NSBundle bundleWithPath:] and check if the bundle identifier matches the one you're looking for.